# Do I have to link my shared library with QWebKit (11Mb) if it's already linked with my host app?

Tags: qt, shared-libraries

I'm writing an app in Qt that is using QWebKit for accessing webpages.
I want to extract some functionality into a dll that can be automatically updated, but it seems like I have to link QWebkit with both host app and my dll, that will add extra 11Mb to application installer and also extra 11Mb for autoupdate is not what I looking for.

Is there any way to link webkit (and xml and gui) only to host application and let shared library use it while loaded into host app?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Qt as shared libraries (dll's) rather than statically linking, then you'll only need to ship one copy of the webkit dll.

If you are statically linking, you'll need to link webkit into which ever part of your app requires it.  If your main app and the part you want to extract both require webkit, then you'll need to link it in twice.

Unless you have a real need to have the smallest program size possible, I would recommend not statically linking to Qt, and just shipping the dlls you require.  It's far less hassle to do it this way than statically linking.

Comment: funny thing is that I use QT as shared library in host app, but my dll is linking with QT statically. Can't find any options in QT Creator responsible for that. Where should I check it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Qt Creator.  If you don't see anything obvious in it's project configuration dialogs, You may need to edit the .pro file directly.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like it's somewhere in IDE but I can't find it, or it's not the static linking at all.

Comment: Ok, i found out that that 11Mb was just debug information, in release mode .dll size reduced to about .5Mb and that is nice.